# WordPress is it possible to have search by keyword of standard search query and custom tax_query

Tags: php, wordpress

have query like this:

```
$key = 'xbox';
$test = get_posts( 
    array(
        'suppress_filters' => false,
        's'                => $key,
        'numberposts'      => 10,
        'post_type'        => array('games'),
        'tax_query'              => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'platforms',
                'field'            => 'slug',
                'terms'            => $key,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'genres',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $key,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $key,
            ) 
        )

    ) 
);
```

and I need to have search `s` and tax-query working by both..
for example if I seach xbox I want that query would find and in my posts content/titlte word xbox.. but also check if any post exists in term `LIKE %xbox%`

any suggestions?